# How to set up an upload form in back office of prestashop ?

Tags: php, file-upload, smarty, prestashop

I'm trying to add a menu in the back end office of Prestashop 1.6 that allows the admin to add some image in order to be displayed in a specific category , I need to upload an image to the server How I can set up this functionality safely  using some Prestashop internal functions

Comment: I have added a controller class that load a *.tpl template but I couldn't set up a form to upload an image using native php

Answer (score 3):

not an easy task, I will recommend create a module for doing this otherwise you will need to modify system files of prestashop and you will hook yourself with old version of Prestashop. Its not the complete answer for your question but it may at least point you to the right direction.

here is simple tutorial how to make module

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module

and more specific one for the backend

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+Dashboard+Module

basically use modules to extend any functionality in prestashop to keep it easy to maintain

you may also find necessary to hook your module into prestashop Hooks so you will need to read about them as well

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Hooks

http://mypresta.eu/en/art/developer/prestashop-hook-list.html

Another approach less portable is to override categories here is tutorial how to do it in Ps 1.6
http://nemops.com/prestashop-categories-second-image/

Comment: I need just to upload an image and store the link in the data base so  I added a controller class that load a *.tpl template but I couldn't set up the form to upload using native php

Comment: try this tutorial it have different approach but its also acceptable  http://nemops.com/prestashop-categories-second-image/#.VVSnlPlVhBc